# How to deserialize JSON request from EXT.NET on ASP.NET Web Api side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ext.net

I am trying to make HTTPPOST from webclient using EXT.NET libraries.

Here is how my call looks like

```
 <ext:Button ID="dugmeOdobri" runat="server" Text="Odobri Narudžbe" Icon="Accept" >
                    <DirectEvents>
                        <Click 
                            Success="sayHello(result);"
                            Url="http://dnndev.me:9010/DesktopModules/WebApiSpn/API/odobrenje/odobri" 
                            Type="Load" 
                            Method="POST" 
                            CleanRequest="true" 
                            Json="true" >
                            <ExtraParams>
                                <ext:Parameter Name="Values" Value="Ext.encode(#{DocumentsGrid}.getRowsValues({selectedOnly:true}))" Mode="Raw" />
                            </ExtraParams>
                        </Click>
                    </DirectEvents>
                 </ext:Button>
```

Fiddler and Chromes's F11 capture call like this

```
{"Values":"[{\"ID\":6894443,
            \"SkladisteSifra\":\"001\",
            \"SkladisteNaziv\":\"Skladi\\u0161te Veleprodaje RGT\",
            \"StatusCode\":null,
            \"StatusDescription\":\"Aktivna\",
            \"Broj\":\"000009\",
            \"Datum\":\"2013-06-13T00:00:00\",
            \"PartnerSifra\":\"24055\",
            \"PartnerNaziv\":\"15 APRIL\",
            \"Napomena\":\"UGALJ\",
            \"TipDokumenta\":\"VEL - Narud\\u017eba dobavlja\\u010du-slikovnica  \",
            \"Odobriti\":true,
            \"Editable\":true}
            ]"}
```

When I paste that string to  [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)
I get poco like this :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Values { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to deserialize my request to poco like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SkladisteSifra { get; set; }
    public string SkladisteNaziv { get; set; }
    public object StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string Broj { get; set; }
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    public string PartnerSifra { get; set; }
    public string PartnerNaziv { get; set; }
    public string Napomena { get; set; }
    public string TipDokumenta { get; set; }
    public bool Odobriti { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
}
```

How should looks like method on server side ?
Here what I tried so far one of n combination in last 3 hours

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string odobri(HttpRequestMessage  request)
        {
            Dictionary<string,string> values = request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>().Result;

            narudzbeZaOdobriti c = null; ;
            foreach (string s in values.Values)
            {
                 c = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<narudzbeZaOdobriti>(s);
                 break;
            }
            return c.Broj;

        }
```

I can't get where I do wrong, Is my call to Web Api missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try this :

```
public string odobri(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>().Result;

    RootObject c = null;
    foreach (string s in values.Values)
    {
        List<RootObject> tmp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(s);
        c = tmp.First();
        break;
    }
    return c.Broj;

}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, May I ask you to we together try Deserialize to List directly without deseriazling first to Dictionary<string,string>. Your first answer before edid point me to I can deseriazle to List<RootObject> first. That aprouch is more liked to me. Thany again

Answer (score 2):

Are you forced to use HttpRequestMessage?

Here I have prepared an MVC example.

**View**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new SomeEntity()
                {
                    Test1 = "test11",
                    Test2 = "test12",
                    Test3 = "test13"   
                },
                new SomeEntity()
                {
                    Test1 = "test21",
                    Test2 = "test22",
                    Test3 = "test23"   
                },
                new SomeEntity()
                {
                    Test1 = "test31",
                    Test2 = "test32",
                    Test3 = "test33"   
                }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Submit selected rows" Icon="Accept">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click
                Success="alert(Ext.encode(result));"
                Url="/Aspx/SubmitSelected"
                Method="POST">
                <ExtraParams>
                    <ext:Parameter 
                        Name="values" 
                        Value="Ext.encode(#{GridPanel1}.getRowsValues({ selectedOnly:true }))" 
                        Mode="Raw" />
                </ExtraParams>
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:Button>

    <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store runat="server">
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Test1" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Test2" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Test3" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
        <ColumnModel runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test1" DataIndex="Test1" />
                <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test2" DataIndex="Test2" />
                <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test3" DataIndex="Test3" />
            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server" SelectedIndex="1" Mode="Simple" />
        </SelectionModel>
    </ext:GridPanel>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ext.Net;
using Ext.Net.MVC;

namespace Work2MVC.Controllers
{
    public class AspxController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SubmitSelected(string values)
        {
            List<SomeEntity> data = JSON.Deserialize<List<SomeEntity>>(values);

            return this.Direct(data.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeEntity.cs**

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
    public string Test3 { get; set; }
}
```